# Obtaining a transform for Affine transformation (Cartesian to geodetic coordinate system)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, georeferencing, shapely

I have a Line, defined as 2 points in a Cartesian coordinate system.

Shapely allows projecting this line with an affine transformation if a transform is specified.

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform

coef_6_transform = [0.10000036968576852, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1000006060605726, 350482.8259, 5617200.9533]
# obtained from a .geotif raster
def to_Shapley_Line(line):

    p0, p1 = line
    A = Point(p0[0],p0[1])
    B = Point(p1[0],p1[1])

    return LineString([A, B])

def vectorize_line(line):
   return affine_transform(to_Shapley_Line(line), coef_6_transform)
```

This works perfectly but does not fit my needs. Exporting a file as `.geotiff` and reloading it is way too slow.

As far as I understand this, is the `coef_6_transform` the mapping of a from  a linear map (a.k.a. cathesian coordinate system) to the defined CRS.

If I provide the CRS and a location, can I obtain this transform without extracting it from a  `.geotiff`?

Or

What is the name of the my local matrix, that starts at 0 ? I would like to et it with geopandas `.set_crs()`; afterwards i could reproject with `.to_crs`

example to clarify :

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, Polygon
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform
from owslib.wms import WebMapService
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from rasterio.plot import show
        

# Geotiff Extraction; i want to extract as a jpeg instead, to save download and computation Time

WMS_url_hist = "https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_hist_dop?"       
wms_hist = WebMapService(WMS_url_hist)

crs = "EPSG:25832"  
shp_geom  = Polygon(((351511.3832, 5616978.270700001), (351552.41784617, 5616997.140201801),
                     (351636.0678615501, 5617035.606090089), (351800.7549000001, 5617111.3363),
                     (351804.7563000001, 5617104.792899999), (351837.5250559599, 5617051.2122095),
                     (351888.6184044101, 5616967.669299701), (351621.72937412, 5616845.93172588),
                     (351619.2559, 5616849.2452), (351605.7223457001, 5616865.068229449),
                     (351586.34850795, 5616887.719544729), (351568.5424999999, 5616908.5378),
                     (351554.46985843, 5616925.705787269), (351543.1406684901, 5616939.5276307),
                     (351529.7399, 5616955.877399999), (351511.3832, 5616978.270700001)))
#print("shp_geom ",shp_geom )
bounds = shp_geom.bounds
#results in :
#bb order (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)                       
bounds = (351511.38320000004, 5616845.93172588, 351888.6184044101, 5617111.3363)
img = wms_hist.getmap(layers=["nw_hist_dop_2013"],
                    styles=["default"],
                    srs=crs,
                    bbox=bounds,
                    #size=(3774,2654),
                    size=(3000, 2500), # The original resolution is 10cm
                    format='image/tiff',#'image/jpeg',#Here word be a change for the other Case
                    transparent=True
                    )
out = open("Test.tif", 'wb')
out.write(img.read())
out.close()





#This line is extracted from the picture above
line = ((1068, 1908), (1351, 1757))

def to_Shapley_Line(line):

    p0, p1 = line
    A = Point(p0[0],p0[1])
    B = Point(p1[0],p1[1])

    return LineString([A, B])

# i would like to infer the right 6 parameter Transform (coeff_6_transform) from the length of the bounding Box
src = rasterio.open("Test.tif")#.jpeg
transform = src.transform
coef_6_transform = [element for tupl in transform.column_vectors for element in tupl]
print("coef_6_transform",coef_6_transform)
# results in :
# coef_6_transform = [0.1257450681366632, 0.0, 0.0, -0.10616182964801991, 351511.38320000004, 5617111.3363]
# the 2nd and 3rd parameter need to be 0, as i observed
# the 5th and 6th parameter are the minx and maxy of the bounding box
# the 1st and 4th parameter are due to the extraction of a 10 cm spatial resolution image wich a size of 3000,2500
# (3774,2654) would be more accurate and resilt in theese coefficients beeing closer to 10, but not exactly 10, unfortunatly
# is there a way of calculating the 1st and 4th paramter, just from the bounding Box and the 10cm resolution ?


def vectorize_line(line):
    #transforms the line into the desired crs
   return affine_transform(to_Shapley_Line(line), coef_6_transform)


transformed_line = vectorize_line(line)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
show(src, ax=ax)
gpd.GeoSeries(transformed_line).plot(ax=ax, color = "red", linewidth = 1)
plt.savefig("Test.png")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Do you need to find the parameters of the transformation that transforms the local Cartesian coordinates into coordinates of some cartographic system? Do you know the coordinates you want to reach? Do you know the cartographic system in which you want to reference the line? Will you take into account cartographic deformations in the transformation? I can help you find transformation parameters, but I don't quite understand what you are needing.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Yes from a local matrix that starts at 0,0. Yes, but I only know a polygon surrounding all lines. Yes, I know it by epsg code. The Lines are extracted from a DOP and never exceed a few 100 meters, thus they possibly do not need to be realigned.

Comment: I still don't understand why you take the transformation parameters from a geotiff, can you provide a reproducible, example?

Comment: That's exactly the point, I don't want to take the parameters from the GeoTIFF. I want to infer them from the provided bounding box alone. I also know the resolution. An example would be possible, if this does not clear things for you.

Comment: Yes, please, if you have the bounding box coordinates in both systems, or the information that you have, plase share it so we can find the parameters of the transformation.

Comment: I added an example; thanks fir your help

Answer (score 1):

That 6 coefficients affine transformation matrix is the georeference of the image. It is determined by its bounds and resolution, to be able to transform coordinates of columns and rows of pixels to EPSG:25832 referenced coordinates.

Yo can see how it works in the description of world files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

---

You have the georeferenced bounds of the image, because it is based on a shapely Polygon object that you have created, and you define the size of the pixels when you assign the rows and columns of the raster to be saved (`size = (3000, 2500)`).

You are drawing a line in the internal pixels coordinates system of the image, so you can georeference the line in the same way as the raster is georeferenced.

Just need to compute the size of the pixels, and take into account that the internal system of the image has the `(0, 0)` coordinate in the upper left corner, so the `y` size is a negative value:

```
# Provided data
bounds = (351511.38320000004, 5616845.93172588, 351888.6184044101, 5617111.3363)
size = (3000, 2500)

# Compute the parameters of the georeference
A = (bounds[2] - bounds[0]) / size[0] # pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
B = 0 # rotation about y-axis
C = 0 # rotation about x-axis
D = -(bounds[3] - bounds[1]) / size[1] # pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative
E = bounds[0] # x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
F = bounds[3] # y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel

coef_6_transform = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

print("coef_6_transform = ",coef_6_transform)
# results in :
# coef_6_transform =  [0.12574506813668024, 0, 0, -0.10616182964779436, 351511.38320000004, 5617111.3363]
```